# no actualiza una tabla del formulario

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

[image: No me actualiza el usuario a pesar de enviar los datos correctamente]
[image: código en php]

**Cuando oprimo el boton actualizar los datos no me permite realizar actualización alguna de la tabla **

Comment: Saludos. Debes poner còdigo; te comento; antes del `WHERE` tienes una coma, yo com regla general al asignar propiedad `name` también pongo el `id` y viceversa(salvo por la acción no se requiera -sea en el BackEnd o FrontEnd). Apoyate en `echo` para obtener la sentencia SQL a ejecutarse para probarla por separado (usarla directo en phpmyadmin o de IDE de BD que  uses). Asì mismo el (correspondiente) proceso para imprimir el error generado/retornado por MySQL.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima :)

Comment: @christianalvarez si necesitas ayuda por favor lee [ask], edita tu pregunta y coloca el código como texto, así como también provee una mejor explicación del problema

Comment: Excelente lo tomare en cuenta.. apenas me inicio en el mundo del desarrollo.

Comment: Revisa bien la base de dato y compara con tu codigo php.